# Sql запрос перенести данные из одной таблице в другую

Tags: sql

у меня есть задание задание В таблицу nomenclatureremains перенесите данные из таблицы nomenclaturesale (Quantity со знаком минус!!!); у меня в таблице nomenclatureremains  уже есть данные, как перенести столбец Quantity со знаком минус
[image: nomenclaturesale]
[image: nomenclatureremains]

Comment: не ясно за чем дело встало, `insert into t1 select -q from t2` или что? иль заминусовать надо значения из существующих а недостающие вставить?

Comment: выдает ошибку #1136 - Количество столбцов не совпадает с количеством значений в записи 1 запрос: insert into nomenclatureremains select -Quantity from nomenclaturesale

Comment: очевидно, если таблицы имеют разные структуры, надо указать поля, которые вы собираетесь вставлять и выбирать их `insert into t1 (field1, field2) select (field1, field2) from t2`

Comment: как можно изменить только один столбец а остальные оставить без изменений

Comment: для этого данные надо не вставлять, а обновлять. я в первом комментарии у вас спросил, что  надо сделать, вставить все, или обновить значения. Начните с того, чтобы корректно формулировать вопросы, желательно с примерами данных в текстовом виде. Для обновления существуюих значений вам потребуется update запрос где обе таблицы вы соедините через оператор `inner join`  а-ля `update  from t1 inner join t2 on t1.code = t2.code and ..... set t1.value = t1.value - t2.values`. до всех ваших махиниций настоятельно рекомендую сделать бэкап базы или копии таблиц.